# How can I iterate over Array.prototype functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I want to wrap all Array functions in array object, but in console

```
>>> Array.prototype
[]
>>> [].prototype
undefined
```

but when I type `Array.prototype` in console it show all functions in autocomple, how can I get those functions? Where are they hidden?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

do you mean:

```
var arrObj = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype);
for( var funcKey in arrObj ) {
   console.log(arrObj[funcKey]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was searching for. Thanks.

Comment: Do note that `arrObj` is actually an array and [looping an array with for..in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript) has it's drawbacks.

Comment: Sudhir this doesnt return the prototype property names when you pass an instance of the prototype eg `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myArr);` is this possible?

Comment: @wal you should be able to use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myArr.__proto__)`. I know this is an old question but someone just upvoted my question and I've checked the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Using ECMAScript 6 (ECMAScript 2015), you can simplify a bit:

```
for (let propName of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype)) {
   console.log(Array.prototype[propName]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var proto = Array.prototype;

for (var key in proto) {
    if (proto.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + ' : ' + proto[key]);
    }
}
```

[demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/6p6Sp/)

And if you want to check its property in console.

Use: `console.dir(Array.prototype);`

​

Comment: This don't work. (in Google chrome), as I put in question, Array.prototype is empty array when access it in this way.

Comment: It don't, that's why I ask this question. `console.dir(Array.prototype);` return array[0] with those functions, but iterating over Array.prototype don't work.

Comment: Do you mean you don't see the property in the console?

Comment: No, did you? Chrome, Opera and Firefix don't show them (console.dir work but only in console, and in Opera it look like you call that function when you type Array.prototype), you can only iterate over prototype content that you create by yourself, but not default functions that are put into prototype by browser like `Array.prototype.pop`. Aditionaly `[].prototype` is undefined to get prototype of Array object I need to use `[].constructor.prototype`

Comment: @xdazz Your demo loads mootools, and it outputs only the methods added to Array.prototype by mootools http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Array. (`getRandom` is listed, but `map` isn't.)

Comment: It does not work for me either in 2019 using firefox.